# How to setup jdbc connection to Mysql in AWS instance?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have a mysql running in an ec2 instance, when I try to use that mysql, I can do follows:

```
dilin-mbp:~ dilin$ ssh -i /Users/dilin/Documents/SelfProject/MM_AWS_MainKey.pem ec2-user@54.69.23.214  
Last login: Tue Feb 24 05:07:47 2015 from c-73-189-116-135.hsd1.ca.comcast.net

   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
  ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-release-notes/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-45-13 ~]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1969
Server version: 5.5.42 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select * from .....;
```

That is, I need to first use a pem file to access the server and then I can use mysql.

Here comes the question, in JDBC, how can I confinger the pem file to make myself get connected?

My naive implementation:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://54.69.23.214:3306/";
    String dbName = "snapsono";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "pwd";
    SnapList snapList = new SnapList();
    try {
        Driver mysqlDriver = (Driver) Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(mysqlDriver);
        logger.info("about to get access");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName,
                userName, password);
        logger.info("get Initialized!!!");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM event");
        while (res.next()) {
            int id = res.getInt("userid");
            String idUrl = res.getString("url");
            SnapProfile profile = new SnapProfile(id,idUrl);
            snapList.getList().add(profile);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In currently implementation, according to the log, I cannot set up the connection, and server does not response. I guess that is because I did not setup the pem file, can anyone help me to finger out the setting?

```
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 40 seconds.
Feb 24, 2015 8:51:16 PM snap.sono.demo.impl.GeneralImpl getDbHello
INFO: >>> enter getDbHello
Feb 24, 2015 8:51:16 PM snap.sono.demo.impl.GeneralImpl getDbHello
INFO: about to get access
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link     failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because your AWS Instance is configured to connect to port 3306 from localhost only, more precisely it is allowed to connect from EC2-Instance IP only.
So, 
Login to your `AWS Console` and edit allocated `Security Group Policy` and make it to Allow to connect from Any IP. 
You can refer to this link for editing Security Group Policy, It is for SSH but process is same for MySQL, except that you will need to add new rule for MySQL.
[.AWS REF.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)
Secondly, Create a new mysql user as follows
`create user 'appuser'@'localhost' identified by 'pass123';`
`create user 'appuser'@'%' identified by 'pass123';`
`grant all privileges on *.* to 'appuser'@'localhost'`
`grant all privileges on *.* to 'appuser'@'%';`
So that you would be able to connect to `mysql` from any IP or If you have a static one then I would suggest you to use that instead of `%` due to security concerns :)

Comment: I know that maybe a port connection issue, but in the security group I grant  access from my current ip, and as you can see from my post, I do able to get access from ip, maybe I should use ssh to do local port forwarding

Comment: I guess you have granted SSH access from your IP, So telnet your EC2 on port 3306 from your system and see if it is able to connect. also your system's firewall might be the culprit.